# using php, how do i upload youtube videos on my site using the youtube v3 api?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am doing this website where the user registers and uploads a video using youtube link.
I don't want to use a Youtube Channel.
I am new to programming in php and i have no idea as to how to go about this.
The page also has to have a category list of the videos on the website after the user uploads a video.

Any help would be appreciated

edit: here is what i got so far, i don't know how i got here, all i know is that it doesn't work.
It has a modal which lets the user input the video link and import it to a page that  will display all videos.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="video-embed-iframe">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$videos_youtube_id}?autoplay={$player_autoplay}&showinfo={$player_showinfo}&rel={$player_related}&controls={$player_controls}&loop={$player_loop}&color={$player_color}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="upload-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span> {$lang_upload_new_videos}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="upload-message"></div>
        <form id="upload-form" method="POST" action="">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">              
            <label for="category">{$lang_category} <span>*</span> </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                {section name=x loop=$categories}
                    <option value="{$categories[x].id}">{$categories[x].category}</option>
                {/section}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="link">{$lang_videos_link} <span>*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link" dir="ltr" id="link" placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJcB3ZaaLlA" />
            <p class="help-block" dir="ltr">youtube video link</p>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="import_btn" class="btn btn-inverse pull-left">{$lang_import}</button>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For example, you should start by [checking out the youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

Comment: i checked out the youtube documentation, thats number one. number two is php documentation both confuse me a whole more. That is why i am asking the question. Read the question "I AM NEW TO PROGRAMMING IN PHP".

I even tried to do it but my solution is weak, doesnt work at all.
Like i said, i am very new to php, first week of doing it.

Rather than  shoot me down like that, why didnt you come back with something more positive.

I have been doing proper research but still stuck hence im asking, i wouldnt have asked if i knew this would be the response one will get.

Comment: You should always include all you've done in the original post. Otherwise we have no idea what you've read or what you've tried. We're glad to help, but we do need to know what (or if) you have made any attempts. SO has guidelines about writing questions. I did include links to a couple of them in my original comment. It wasn't out of ill will, but rather to let you know why the question was lacking and how to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you are new to PHP as well I suggest you dig in a bit more on the matter.

But this is a working code, that hopefully help you a bit.

```
if($client->getAccessToken()) {
$snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle("Test title");
$snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
$snippet->setTags(array("tag1","tag2"));
$snippet->setCategoryId("22");

$status = new Google_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "private";

$video = new Google_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

$error = true;
$i = 0;

try {
    $obj = $youTubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
                                     array("data"=>file_get_contents("video.mp4"), 
                                    "mimeType" => "video/mp4"));
} catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
    print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage(). " <br>";
    print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you.
You have no idea how stressed i am. I'm completely stuck.
At first i had a video and a popup modal but non of them worked, i kept seeing the same code and the dived into the documentation. i got lost even more.

Comment: yes, I get that a lot. Sometimes, its better to call it a day, and start fresh tomorrow.